# Выполнить одно из условий в цикле FOR (PHP)

Tags: циклы

можно ли в цикле сделать оба условия? При срабатывании одного из условий выполнить нужные действия.

1. Задача  Функция должна выводить строку от меньшего к большему через пробел. Т.е. если числа 3 и 6 то выводим // 3 4 5 6
2. Задача Если 6 и 3 то результат // 6 5 4 3

---

```
    function t4()
{
    global $num1, $num2, $out4;
    $x = "";

    for ($i = $num1; $i <= $num2 or  $j = $num1; $j >= $num2; $i++; $j = $j - 2;){
        $x .= $i." ";
    }

        $out4 = $x;
    echo $out4;
}
```

Comment: `$x = $num1; while (($s = ($num1 <=> $num2)) != 0) { $x .= ' ' . ($num1 -= $s); }`

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я не знаю как тут еще можно говорить спасибо (карма, рейтинг и т.д) Напишете нажму куда надо ))